# ClassCastException ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String when deserializing

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, classcastexception

I am trying to serialize, send and receive an instance of the below class ( ServerGameDataObject object = new ServerGameDataObject() )

```
public class ServerGameDataObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5410058267505412928L;

    private TestClass t1 =null;
    private TestClass t2 =null;

    public ServerGameDataObject(){

        t1 = new TestClass();
        t2 = new TestClass();

    }
}
```

The definition of TestClass in it is :

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class TestClass  implements Serializable{
    transient public static final long serialVersionUID = -3089302783006861199L;

    private int val =-1;
    public  TestClass(){
        val=-1;

    }
}
```

.....
The object is sent as follows:

```
    ObjectOutputStream o = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(
            <some outputstream>);

    o.writeUnshared(object);
    o.flush();
```

The definition of AppendingObjectOutputStream is:

```
public class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
        // do not write a header, but reset:
        // this line added after another question
        // showed a problem with the original
        reset();
    }

}



 The code on the receiving end is :

    Object o = null;
   while ((o = inputStream.readUnshared()) != null) { // this is Receiver.java, line 74
    ...
    }

inputStream is an instance of ObjectInputStream
```

On the receiving end this exception is thrown:

```
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133): FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Thread-134 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast
> to java.lang.String 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldDescriptors(ObjectInputStream.java:935)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:1744)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1656)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1140)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1372)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1269)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1858)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:1978)
> 05-10 10:54:51.572: E/AndroidRuntime(3133):   at
> Receiver.run(Receiver.java:74)
```

If inside ServerGameDataObject I define t2 to be transient (transient private TestClass t2 =null; ), then I DO REICEIVE the objects

What's wrong? Why can i NOT receive both t1 and t2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Numerous mistakes here.

1. You must use a normal `ObjectOutputStream` for the first write, and the appending version only when you are appending. If the output is a socket it really makes more sense just to use the same `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the socket.
2. `readObject()` and `readUnshared()` don't return `null` at EOS. They throw `EOFException`. So looping while they don't return null is incorrect.

Comment: 1. I do that already <some outputstream> above is obtained after the first write 

2. I will look into it. Regardless, the application works when one of the two TestClasses is transient. I need to get it working when none is transient.

Comment: In that case the class that doesn't work probably has an incorrect readObject() or writeObject() method.